# TypeError: 'set' object is not callable [PYTHON]

Tags: python, set

viewed some other forums to see if I could find an answer to this but I didn't find anything satisfactory. I'm writing a program to work out the fibonacci sequence up to a specified index, but I keep getting an error.

```
allNums = {1, 1}

while len(allNums) < 35:
    currentIndex = len(allNums)
    nextIndex = allNums[currentIndex - 1] + allNums[currentIndex - 2]
    allNums[currentIndex] = nextIndex
    print(nextIndex)
```

This is working fine on my laptop, but for some reason when I try it on my desktop it gives me the error:
`nextIndex = allNums(currentIndex - 1) + allNums(currentIndex - 2)`
`TypeError: 'set' object is not callable`

Any help?

Comment: Compare the error message to the code you've posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets do not support calling `allNums(currentIndex - 1)` nor are subscriptable (i.e allow index assigning) `allNums[currentIndex - 1]`. There are designed for quick search of items, not storing them in order.

You need `allNums` to be a list, not a set:

```
allNums = [1, 1]

while len(allNums) < 35:
    currentIndex = len(allNums)
    nextIndex = allNums[currentIndex - 1] + allNums[currentIndex - 2]
    allNums.append(nextIndex)
    print(nextIndex)
```

Output:

```
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
...
```

Comment: LOL! I feel so dumb now haha, I think my math class earlier made me confuse curly brackets with normal brackets. Thank you!